# How to run 32bit Java 6 on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am working with an eclipse plugin that requires it to run 32bit Java6 on it and I do have Java 6 on my computer but when I run the program I get this error.

```
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
Linking the file failed with exit status 1
```

The Java 6 I installed was from Apple's legacy Java 2015.
In the installation tutorial of the plug in it said that

> Note that even if you have a 64-bit system, leJOS will always chose to run java in 32 Bit mode by automatically passing the -d32 parameter to the java command whenever necessary.

If that is the case why doesn't my program run if I have Legacy Java 6 installed on my Mac?

Comment: Do you have a 32 bit version of Eclipse?

Comment: I have this Java installed which should have 32bit support for Java https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US @KevinO

Comment: This may be impossible on recent mac OS versions. What is your OS version? What output do you get for `java -version -d32` and `java -version`? Make sure the `java` on your path points to that legacy Java6 you installed (I think there is a preference panel to select that).

Comment: It is possibly irrelevant that the Java has support for 32 bit if the Eclipse doesn't have libraries to support 32-bit. AFAIK, all recent versions of Eclipse for the Mac are 64-bit (they have native libraries; Eclipse is not pure Java).

Comment: I am on macOS Sierra 10.12 @Thilo

Comment: @KevinO I am working with a Lego NXT and they run 32bit bit and I was following the tutorial they posted for Mac uses. Trying to run LeJOS for eclipse

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber Maybe crosspost over at the Bricks Exchange: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/does-the-mindstorms-ev3-software-work-on-macos-sierra

Comment: I already have Lego programming software on my Mac but there is a separate thing called LeJOS which is Java programming for the NXT Intelligent brick. You use eclipse Java to program it @Thilo

Comment: Right, and I think the folks over at Bricks might know more about this than the general Stackoverflow population.